# How do I add a file to the repository that was deleted (Visual Studio Code)?

Tags: visual-studio, github, repository

I recently got my folder connected to my repository on GitHub but in the process I clicked on something and my `index.html` got deleted. I dragged it back to the folder on Visual Studio Code, yet it is not highlighted in green with A like all the others. I am guessing it is not connected to the repository.

How do I add the `index.html` to be a part of the others highlighted?

[image: Screenshot of the issue]

Comment: Thank you! New to the website.

Answer (score 0):

Few things you can do, you can pull down the repository again, but no point in this as it seems you have the latest.

You can perform git stash. This will revert all changes made in the current commit, and will bring back the file you deleted. (This will also stash all the changes you have made).

Or you can push all your changes to the repository, and this will just mean your repo is up to date.

Bear in mind, the 'A' doesn't mean that the files are connected, it just means they are recently added. Adding files to the folder wont mean they are "Connected" as you say to the repo, but when you push up the changes they will be present. Deleting the file and pushing the changes up will cause them to be deleted from the repo. Deleting the file and readding it like you have should be fine